# GoTo function is corrupt or has a limit

Tags: excel, vba

I want to put two GoTo aligned after detecting an error. However, the second GoTo is ignored by VBA, and then a debug screen appears.

```
Sub GoTo_Test()

Dim X, Y As Integer

1: On Error GoTo 2
                                            MsgBox "START 1"
    X = 1 / 0
                                            MsgBox "END 1"

2: On Error GoTo 3
                                            MsgBox "START 2"
    Y = 1 / 0
                                            MsgBox "END 2"

3:                                          MsgBox "End Sub"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've entered an error handler subroutine, you need to exit that subroutine with `Resume`. Because you never did, the second exception is treated as an exception inside an error handler, which means the error handler failed to handle the error, so the error is propagated up.

If you insist on having the code laid out the way you sketched out, that would be

```vb
Sub GoTo_Test()
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer

1: On Error GoTo 2
                                            MsgBox "START 1"
    X = 1 / 0
                                            MsgBox "END 1"

handled_2: On Error GoTo 3
                                            MsgBox "START 2"
    Y = 1 / 0
                                            MsgBox "END 2"

handled_3:                                  MsgBox "End Sub"

Exit Sub


2:
Resume handled_2

3:
Resume handled_3

End Sub
```

Comment: You could also use `On Error Resume Next` then. At least you will get the same result. On the other hand I do not know what the OP really wants to learn by the code above,

Comment: @Storax The result will not be the same. With `On Error Resume Next` you will see `"END 1"` and `"END 2"`. Here, you won't.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to reset the error handler.

```
Sub GoTo_Test()

        Dim X, Y As Integer

1:        On Error GoTo 2
          MsgBox "START 1"
          X = 1 / 0
          MsgBox "END 1"

2:        On Error GoTo -1
          On Error GoTo 3
          MsgBox "START 2"
          Y = 1 / 0
          MsgBox "END 2"

3:        MsgBox "End Sub"

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, I now understand the purpose of GoTo -1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoTo_Test()

Dim X, Y As Integer

1: On Error GoTo 2
                                            MsgBox "START 1"
    X = 1 / 0
                                            MsgBox "END 1"

2: Resume Next
On Error GoTo 3
                                            MsgBox "START 2"
    Y = 1 / 0
                                            MsgBox "END 2"

3: Resume Next
                                            MsgBox "End Sub"

End Sub
```

You need to close (terminate) each active error handler else you'll have problems with errors within the active error handling routine.